# How to manually adjust video card fan speed

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card

I have a XFX GT240 video card, and the fan in constantly running at one speed. The EVGA and MSI control software do not work to control the speed.

Is there a way to modify the card to allow it to change speeds? If I were to replace the fan, would I then be able to control the fan speed via the card and software?

I'm on Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of freeware programs that comes to mind, namely [RivaTuner](http://www.guru3d.com/index.php?page=rivatuner) and [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php).

Bear in mind the implications of setting the fan speed by yourself. Setting the fan speed too low while playing a game or other similar task could shorten your GPU's lifespan.

Answer (score 0):

The way to be sure is to look at the card itself; if the fan cable is only two wires then doing it in software is nigh-impossible (you'd have to actually regulate the voltage going out).  If it's more, it has a control channel so in theory it's possible, but in practice the card might not cooperate or there might just not be software written for it.  In short - you'll probably have to deal with it.  (Alternatively, you could solder a small resistor into the fan cable...)

EDIT: It's nigh-impossible safely.  It can certainly be done on a lot of hardware but I wouldn't feel comfortable treating my hardware that way - it's a good way to potentially damage it.

Comment: indeed there are only two wires, red and black. What's the best way to set out to have a controllable fan?

Comment: The best way is to do your homework before you buy - a lot of cards will in fact handle fan throttling themselves.  As happy_soil's good answer points out, RivaTuner and SpeedFan are widely used for cards that don't (I have no experienec with SpeedFan myself though) but as I said your mileage may vary - the best thing is just to check online to see if anybody else has had trouble getting them to work.